# How to use $each.$iter within vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I raised an issue with vuelidate https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/388 and was given a response.

> Refrain from looping the $each.$iter property and using it to v-model data to it.

I am however unsure what the best approach is to use here as I am following the documentation given by vuelidate. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction of what the best approach is when using $each.$iter within vuelidate.

Example code can be seen here https://codesandbox.io/s/84vpkojoxl

Comment: It's odd that they're recommending against a pattern described in their docs. FWIW, I cannot reproduce the error mentioned in the GitHub issue, using your demo repo, but I'm using macOS (and it looks like you're on Windows).

Comment: Im not sure that the error is there any more as they may have fixed it in the vue test util side. But like you said it is odd for them to suggest a pattern against the documentation. It may due to the vuex not being used in the documentation. Just trying to understand if there was a better pattern to be used.